# $_SESSION variables always printing 'S' and not intended variable when set

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
include 'config.php';
$referencenumber=$_POST['reference_number'];
$fullname=$_POST['full_name'];
$sRef=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$referencenumber);
$sName=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$fullname);
$query="SELECT * From customers where reference_number='$sRef' and 
full_name='$sName'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $query['id'];
    $_SESSION['refnumber'] = $query['reference_number'];
    header('location:index.php');
}
}

?>
```

The above code is what I have written on my login.php page. After a successful login, the user arrives at the index.php page.

```
var lz_data = {overwrite:true,111:'<?php 
print_r($_SESSION['refnumber'])?>',
```

I am then attempting to print the reference number on the next page here, which will set a value that matches the one in $_SESSION['refnumber'] but for some reason the output of this code always seems to be 'S' when printing, just the letter S. I get the same output when I try to print $_SESSION['id'] as well. Any ideas?

EDIT: session_start(); has been added at the start of index.php, and the double quotations didn't solve the issue.

Comment: `var lz_data = {overwrite:true,111:'<?php 
print_r($_SESSION["refnumber"])?>',`

Comment: have you add session_start() in the index.php ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI yeah I added session_start(); at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to get a specific index of a string instead of the result / row array:

```
$query="SELECT * From customers where reference_number='$sRef' and full_name='$sName'";
$_SESSION['id'] = $query['id']; // $query is a string not an array.
$_SESSION['refnumber'] = $query['reference_number']; // $query is a string not an array.
```

**Why you only get "S" on the session?**

You can use a string value on PHP like an array. So you can use `$query[0]` to get the "S" and `$query[1]` to get the "E" and so on. In your case the `$query['id']` is the same like `$query[0]` because `var_dump('id' == 0)`  is true.

[**demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/g5g9Ns)

**How to solve this?**

You can use the [`mysqli_result::fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) method to get the row with columns as index from `$result`:

```
//get the $row from $result with fetch_array.
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//now you can use the row array to set the values to the session.
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION['refnumber'] = $row['reference_number'];
```

So your code looks like the following:

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
    include 'config.php';

    $referencenumber = $_POST['reference_number'];
    $fullname = $_POST['full_name'];

    $sRef = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $referencenumber);
    $sName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $fullname);

    $query = "SELECT * From customers where reference_number='$sRef' and full_name='$sName'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {

        //get the $row from $result with fetch_array.
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['refnumber'] = $row['reference_number'];
        header('location:index.php');
    }
}
```